# How to add ASCII code 0x00 to a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I'm trying to send command through TCP/IP with socket connection, where the command format is as follow:

```
/* send command along with 2-byte data points

         string      2 bytes       2 bytes       2 bytes     ...   termination
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Command   |   0x0000   |    0x0080    |   0xff7f  |  ...  |  '\n'  |
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------

*/
```

Data points are read from a text file and I convert it to string. And I need to send them together instead of sending them separately with string and bit stream.
Command example: "C1:WVDT WVNM,testwave,WAVEDATA," with 2-byte data points.

What I did is like:

```
std::string command(int ch, std::string parameter){

    std::ifstream f_in(parameter, std::ios::in);
    std::string wavename;
    std::string point;
    std::string dataPoints_str;
    short point_2b;    //2-byte signed integer
    f_in>>wavename;
    while(f_in>>point){
        point_2b = htons(stoi(point, 0, 16));   //convert to 2-byte hex integer and to big-endianness
        dataPoints_str += reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b);
    }
    f_in.close();
    return "C" + std::to_string(ch) + ":WVDT WVNM," + wavename + ",WAVEDATA," + dataPoints_str + "\n";
}
```

but after I add points to string all '0x00' values just disappeared.
i.e. in text file I wrote:

```
waveformname
0x0000
0x8000
0x7fff
```

only 0x80 and 0x7fff will be added into the string.
How can I also add 0x00 into string?

Comment: `dataPoints_str += reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b);` is problematic, `dataPoints_str.append(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b), 2);` might be better.

Comment: and replacing `f_in>>point` by `f_in >> char_1 >> char_2`.

Comment: concatenating with what equals to empty string literal likely wouldn't do anything, because operation respects terminating zero. `reinterpret_cast`is  also problematic.

Comment: C++ strings can handle null bytes without problems. It's C strings (`char *`) that cannot. If your question were just about adding null bytes to a string, the answer would be easy, but your question also does include a `parameter` that's not used anywhere, some not too elegant stream wiggling, a questionable conversion and a `reinterpret_cast` (which, basically, is always an error), unfortunately turning a two-line answer into a lengthy code review....

Comment: Consider using `span::as_bytes` instead of `reinterpret_cast` if it is available.

Comment: _Side note:_ Consider using `std::int16_t` instead of `short`. That way, the compiler will check your assumption that variable `point_2b` uses two bytes.

Comment: I really recommend having it looked at over on [codereview.se] when you have it finished to your satisfaction - there's a lot that can be made more robust, and the readability could probably be improved too.

Comment: Is the format under your control?  You'll need to do something sooner rather than later to deal with terminating your binary data with newline, given that `\n` could legitimately occur within it.  Either use a length prefix, or give up on binary and make the points readable (e.g. using hexadecimal).  Your maintainers will thank you for that.

Comment: The format is not under my control...I'm just a user of some function generator and trying to control it through TCP/IP.

Comment: Are you sure that data points aren't in plain text? Similar protocols I'm familiar with - GPS units, modems, some sensor software - uses text datapoints with least-significant-bit value.

Comment: That's what I tried...but it's not ASCII encoded text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the overload of `std::string::append` that takes a `char *` and a length, rather than a pointer to null-terminated string of characters:

```
dataPoints_str.append(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b), sizeof point_2b);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will it be a problem of "+" signs in my last line of code "return ..."?

Comment: @Crisps it might be. I've run into webAsm implementation of `std::string` which at least breaks there. it's better use length-based `append` or using `std::string` as a buffer and fill it directly - at least that's how Google does with their protobuf library.

Comment: I changed the last line to ``` std::string command = "C" + std::to_string(ch) + ":WVDT WVNM," + wavename + ",WAVEDATA,"; command.append(dataPoints_str, dataPoints_str.length() );command.append("\n");return command; ``` but I'm not sure if this is better and no problem...

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
dataPoints_str += reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b);
```

When `point_2b` is 0x0000, that's effectively

```
dataPoints_str += "\0\0\0\0";
```

Appending a `char*` to a `std::string` is effectively, "append all the bytes until the first null char". And since the first char is null, there's nothing to append.

Change it to this:

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&point_2b);
dataPoints_str.push_back(ptr[0]);
dataPoints_str.push_back(ptr[1]);
```

The above will explicitly append the two bytes onto the string regardless of whether they are null or not.

Comment: Reading `point` is also problematic.

Answer (score 0):

`+` and `+=` are string concatenation operations and they treat their pointer arguments as null-terminated strings.

Use of `reinterpret_cast` is non-idiomatic here. `htons`, if that's a standard `htons` implementation, is also the slowest way to convert endianness. You're better off doing something equal to

```
// note, you need unsigned for shift to be defined
// unsinged short
uint16_t point_2b = ...
dataPoints_str.push_back((point_2b & 0xFF00) >> 8);
dataPoints_str.push_back(point_2b & 0x00FF);
```

This code clearly shows its intent without any implementation-defined quirks and raised eyebrows at `reinterpret_cast` from code reviewers. And it is endianness-agnostic; you don't need a `hton` call.

And if you are really concerned about performance, you would cache all binary data into a buffer before `resize()`ing the `dataPoints_str` and `std::fill()`ing it, which equals to `std::string::append(const char*, size_t)`.

Comment: Your code has an error: `>>` has higher precedence than `&`, so it adds the lower byte twice.

Comment: @Frodyne Thanks, that was a mispaced sneeze. I guess, human bugs can transfer into code bugs too.

Comment: Your first paragraph is just wrong. `operator+` and `operator+=` do **not** automatically treat their arguments as null-terminated strings -- only if you pass `char *`.

Comment: @DevSolar that would be another operator